# How can I display the description of the JSON that contains 'category':1 without displaying the description of the JSON that contains 'category'=2?

Tags: angular

I'm using this template in Angular:

```
    <div *ngFor='let item of todo' >
        <mat-card class="example-card" >
          
          <img class='imag' mat-card-image src="{{item?.image}}">
          <mat-card-content class='amt'  >
            <p>
              {{item?.description}}
            </p>
          </mat-card-content>
          <mat-card-actions>
            <a class="a" mat-flat-button color="warn" href="{{item?.buy}}" target="_blank">detail </a>
         
          </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
```

`todo` contains these JSON codes:

```
[
            {
                "id": 667,
                "image": "https://ae0g",
                "description": "GRE",
                "price": "USD .11",
                "buy": "https://sn",
                "category": 1
            },
            {
                
                "image": "https://ae04.",
                "description": "10/13 ",
                "price": ".18",
                "buy": "https://",
                "category": 2
            }
]
```

When I use `{{item?.description}}` it displays the `description` of both of JSON codes. How can I display the `description` of the JSON that contains `'category':1` without displaying the `description` of the JSON that contains `'category'=2`?

Comment: Filter your array

Comment: If you wish to hide only the description, then use a `*ngIf` condition in your template

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngif="item?.category == 2">
```